# CSS to animate dropdown menu & change z-index after animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm making a drop down menu with CSS & using CSS `transitions` to fade & move the menu into display. This is working fine by altering the `top` & `opacity` values but the problem is when the menu is hidden it is still over other elements on the page so they cannot be interacted with, even though the menu is not visible.

My solution to this problem is that use `z-index` to place the menu behind everything else when it's not visible but I cannot get it working with the `transitions`. When I use the code below the z-index changes as expected & the menu can be shown & hidden but it does not animate.

```
transition: top 0 .3s ease-in, opacity 0 .3s ease-in, z-index 0;
```

The code below here transitions fine but the z-index change happens before the transitions so you can end up with the z-index putting the menu behind other content then then transition happening where it cannot be seen.

```
transition: top 0 .3s ease-in, opacity 0 .3s ease-in;
```

Comment: What you need is to set the menu's display property to `display: none;`.  Visibility or opacity makes the item "see though", but it still exists in the DOM. Display: none removs it from the DOM. Although I'm not sure how that would work in a transition, if you posted all of the relevant code we could try it.

Comment: you are writing 0 .3s instead of 0.3s

Comment: Most probably you are looking for the `transition-delay` property, but you should include all of the relevant code in the post itself, for us to be able to provide a correct answer.

Comment: @sn3ll `display: none` doesn't work as from what I can tell it cannot be usd in conjunction with transitions, so it'd fix my currently problem but create another (menu would no longer fade).

Comment: @vals I believe the space being there is correct as the `0` signifies the delay (none in this case) and the `.3s` signifies the animation duration.

Comment: @Ricky I believe I am using `transition-delay` but in its shorthand form. I'll add in some example code to my question shortly.

Comment: @NeilNand The `animation-duration` property comes before the `animation-delay` so it would be `.3s 0`. [animation documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), you do not need to specify the delay if it's `0` though.

Comment: The order is duration - delay. So, even in the case that the browser accepts it, it would be a duration of 0s. But Chrome at least doesn't accept it.

Comment: Anyway, you should post a verifiable example (a snippet)

Comment: @vals Yep, I'll add more example code for people to recreate the problem here next time. I might be misinterpreting what you're saying but Chrome does accept the duration & delay in shorthand, I had the ordering wrong for all of it (see my answer for more details).

Comment: @Ricky You're right, I had the whole ordering of values wrong, also I found out that if you do specify a 0 value (although as you said it's not needed) you need to add the unit after, so `0s` in my case. At least that's the case in Chrome at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what my problem is now, I had the shorthand values in the wrong order & the `0`s require the unit of measurement after, so it this case they should have been `0s`.

Here's the working code applied to the non-hover state for the drop down, this takes affect when the menu is transitioning to its hidden state:

```
transition: top .3s ease-in 0s, .3s opacity ease-in 0s, 0s z-index ease-in .3s;
```

Here's the code applied to the hover state of the drop down which takes affect when the menu is transitioning to its visible state.

```
transition: top $default-animation-timing ease-in 0s, $default-animation-timing opacity ease-in 0s, 0s z-index ease-in 0s;
```

As a side note, but related to why I had this problem, when looking up documentation on MDN the "Initial value" list is written in alphabetical order, not in the order the values should be added. I assumed they were in the order they should be used which is why I had my value ordering wrong.

Comment: As @Ricky pointed out in the question comments, the `0s`s can be omitted.